# Distribute iPhone App with product at same time charging for app in iTunes Store?

Tags: iphone, deployment

To make this simple, let's say I have an APP that is related to Golf.  I sell it in the APP store for $5.99.  I've been approached by a company that sells golf clubs, and they want to buy a 'branded' version of the APP to give away to customers when they buy this company's golf clubs (only if the customer buys the clubs).  Can anyone provide ideas on how:  1)  I can maintain the revenue stream of the app currently sold in the APP store and 2)  Provide a branded APP to this company that won't significantly dilute my sales on the original app.  How can the company control distribution of the APP only to their customers without making it 'free' on the open market (which would kill my sales of the original APP).  I am open to all ideas on how to approach this?  I've read through the 'enterprise development' option with Apple, and it looks like using this distribution method would not be applicable as I would not be distributing to devices within my company.

Comment: Business issues like this aren't really appropriate for Stack Overflow.  However, you'll probably find a good audience for this question on the iPhone Software Business mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesb .

Answer (score 1):

Could you make a new FREE branded version of your app?  The app has some views with marketing fluff about the super-great company sponsoring the app; a webview with some nice rich-text, and other info.  App has a "Members Only" view were user can enter some PIN they get from your partner.  Upon entering pin, app will transform into the "paid" version.

In that scenario, I think the trick to get past review is to make the application "useful" to people that do not have the pin.  We're told that Apple doesn't allow useless apps; but I think providing users with information about a product, a small photo gallery, etc, could loosely considered useful.

If the above works, before you release the app; add in the back-end.  You will need to account for users who want to install the app on multiple devices (iPhone, iPad, new iPhone...); but also prevent the registration-PIN from being posted on a mailing list.  You could accomplish this by having the user provide an email address with the PIN and emailing them for confirmation.  When user registers, your app could associate the unique-id of the device with their email; and allow them to have 3-5 activations.  (Build a way to de-authorize a device, or let them call customer service [you] to reset their authorized devices.)

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I had a client who wanted to do a similar thing -- provide specially tailored versions of an app just for attendees of an event.    The un-jailbroken iPhone app market is just not set up for this type of semi-controlled distribution, and the enterprise deployment program doesn't fit this model either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real official way to distribute iOS apps to only a select group of customers or clients in general.

- Enterprise distribution only works
  for employees (and maybe members) of
  a corporation with a D&B rating.
- Ad Hoc apps expire and distribution
  is limited to 100 devices.
- iTunes App store distribution can not
  be limited (except by country, price
  and day of availability).

One options is to distribute the app to everybody, but only have the app download certain content from some website after providing a member or customer login of some sort.  Apple may require this kind of app to also have some general usefulness to the general public.  (Banking apps offer a map to the nearest branch, etc.)

Another option is for the company to sell their branded version of the app in the App store (for a nice price above yours so as not to compete), but gift the app to the iTunes account of their customers (they'll have to eat Apple's 30% as a cost of doing business, except maybe for the first 50 using redemption codes instead).  So their customers will get it for free, but no one else (for free).